# I'm in need of assistance with sequences in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to coding and I can't wrap my head around on how to make a cube in javascript (in my case) move around like x: 100, y: 300 but after it gets there to start moving to a different location as per settings right after completing the last one. For example, at first, he goes to x: 100, y:300, and right after he gets there, he'd go x:600, y:200.

This is what I've got so far:

```
async moveByPath(coordinateArray) {
    coordinateArray.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
        this.move(
            this.x > x ? this.x - x : x - this.x,
            this.y > y ? this.y - y : y - this.y

        );
    });
}

move = (x, y) => {
    return new Promise((res) =>{
        this.target.x = this.x + x;
        this.target.y = this.y + y;
        this.animateMovement(x, y);
        res();
    })
}

animateMovement = (difX, difY) => {
    let directionX = difX < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    let directionY = difY < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    let distance = (difX ** 2 + difY ** 2) ** (0.5);
    let speedX = this.speed * difX / distance * directionX;
    let speedY = this.speed * difY / distance * directionY;
    let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        if ((directionX == 1 && this.x >= this.target.x && directionY == 1 && this.y >= this.target.y) ||
            (directionX == 1 && this.x >= this.target.x && directionY == -1 && this.y <= this.target.y) ||
            (directionX == -1 && this.x <= this.target.x && directionY == 1 && this.y >= this.target.y) ||
            (directionX == -1 && this.x <= this.target.x && directionY == -1 && this.y <= this.target.y)) {
            this.x = this.target.x;
            this.y = this.target.y;
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            this.render();
            return;
            // Path2(test1);
        } else {
            this.x = this.x + speedX;
            this.y = this.y + speedY;
        }
        this.render();
        console.log("this.x=", this.x)
        console.log("this.target.x=", this.target.x)
        // console.log("this.y=", this.y)
        // console.log("this.target.y=", this.target.y)
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how `animateMovement()` is defined?

Comment: You should not use a promise here if you plan to resolve it immediately. If `animateMovement` is doing something asynchronous, *that* function needs to create and return a promise (and fulfill it only when finished).

Comment: Added animateMovement(), thanks for the info.

Comment: If you are new to coding I would recommend you start with the basics before jumping into complex calculations

Comment: I'm working on a project, and this is the only thing that I just can't get past. I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me in detail